# jquery ajax() issue while printing array with each()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my code I am returning an php array containing records of 7 Students. With jquery ajax() I want to print these records on success function.

**DB table Students**

```
+---------------------------+
| name | fathername | Email |
+---------------------------+
```

**submit.php**

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * from Students LIMIT 0,6");

   $row= array();
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
   return json_encode($row);
```

**index.php**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#form1").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                    url:'submit.php',
                    type:'GET',
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(result){
                $.each(result,function(){
                $('.StudentName').text(result["name"]);
                $('.FatherName').text(result["fathername"]);
                $('.Email').text(result["email"]);
                    });

                    }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="StudentName"></div>
<div class="FatherName"></div>
<div class="Email"></div>
```

**EDIT**
I tried to return only 1 result from php and it works i.e.

```
echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($query));
```

When I return all 6 records the jquery function dont execute i.e.

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: What is the return type for your data? JSON, HTML, XML? Your best bet would be to have the PHP create JSON (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and then parse that JSON with your jQuery statement(https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

Comment: I am returning JSON and revised my code as well

Comment: Add `dataType: "json"` to your AJAX function parameters.

Comment: added datatype as well but still not working

Comment: use `echo json_encode($row);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's difference between PHP arrays and JS arrays, you can't simply pass the PHP array to your javascript, so instead you should first [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it and send it to js.

This will convert your PHP array to JSON array, eg:

```
 array(3) {
  [0]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
   string(3) "baz"
  [3]=>
   string(5) "blong"
}
```

to

```
string(33) "{"0":"foo","2":"baz","3":"blong"}"
```

So try -

```
return json_encode($row);
```

and then when you catch the response, use [parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
result = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
$.each(result,function(){
   $('.StudentName').text(result.name);
   $('.FatherName').text(result.fathername);
   $('.Email').text(result.email);
});
```

**Edit:**

Another thing, instead of `return json_encode($row);` write `echo json_encode($row);`

**Edit 2**

(to send all 6 records)

```
$final = array();
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    array_push($final,$result);
}
echo $final;
```

Comment: Can you provide the OP with a more complete answer?

Comment: @SahilMittal `return` must be `echo` ?

Comment: @SahilMittal tried your code but still the same problem. It is not working

Comment: Can you see the result in `console.log(result)`? If yes, post that result here

Comment: I do not know this console.log tag

Comment: Its not a tag, its a jdfunction to output anything in the browser's console. just write it after you get the response and check your browser's console (Ctrl+Shft+J, if chrome)

Comment: @SahilMittal No :( everyone is giving me complicated twisted answers no one is solving

Comment: What's `console.log` is saying?

Comment: @SahilMittal I am using firefox and do not have any idea how console.log works

Comment: Its the most basic thing and most common tool used to debug the web code! Its very strange you never used that! just press F12 and you'll see a console tab there, you can check the output of `console.log` there

Comment: I am not seeing anything in console.log, when I write console.log(result) I see nothing but when I type console.log("hi") I see hi

Comment: I hope you changed `return` to `echo`

Comment: yes I have changed return to echo I figured the function on success is not executing because when I write console.log in it it shows nothing but when I write outside of this function it shows

Comment: You can add  a `fail` sunction and see what's the response

Comment: Or might be that the response is blank, write like this: `console.log("response: "+response);`

Comment: I have write this also still not showing anything in console

Comment: Values are storing in my database via ajax but response is not working

Comment: Its really hard to understand what's happening like this. With the code you've mentioned in the ques, things seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function success(result){
>     $.each(result,function(){
>         $('.StudentName').text(result["name"]);
> ```

looks problematic. There doesn't really seem to be a reason to loop over the `result`, as you assign all of its contents to the same elements in the page.

However, assuming that `result` is an array of objects (like SQL queries usually produce it), then it should be

```
function(result){
    $.each(result,function(obj) {
//    missing parameter!!! ^^^
        $('.StudentName').text(obj["name"]);
//           access that here: ^^^
```

Also do a `console.log(result)` or simply browse the request URL to check whether the PHP scripts yields the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of parsing JSON that may help you - http://jsfiddle.net/Su6QR/

Given that example, change your AJAX function -

```
$.ajax({
    url:'submit.php',
    type:'GET',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success:function(result){
        var members = $.parseJSON(result);
        $.each(members, function() {
            var newStudent = '<span>' + this['name'] + '</span>';
            var newFather = '<span>' + this['father'] + '</span>';
            var newEmail = '<span>' + this['email'] + '</span>';
            $('.StudentName').append(newStudent);
            $('.FatherName').append(newFather);
            $('.Email').append(newEmail);
        });
    }
});
```

This should return all of the data and place them into the divs that you have created. The formatting will not be what you want, but you should be able to fix that pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

Your AJAX

```
        $("#form1").click( function(e){


            var Somename = { };

            $.each($('#form1').serializeArray(), function() {
                Somename [this.name] = this.value;
            });             

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "submit.php",
                data: { upddt_empID: upddt_empID, somevariable: "YES" },
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('Successfull');           
                }
            });
```

Your PHP

```
if(isset( $_REQUEST['somevariable'] ) )
{
   $selItem = YourFunctionName( $_REQUEST['Somename ']['here your textbox id'], $_REQUEST['Somename ']['here your textbox id'],'yourtablename');
}
```

Your Query

```
function YourFunctionName(tablename)
{
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM $tablename";

    $result = mysql_query($qry);

    return $result;
}
```